# How to turn list scrolling off when calling onContentChanged in Android ListActivity?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I got a ListActivity.

I update the activity using onContentChanged() API.

My problem is that each time I call the above API the list scrolls to the top. Is there any easy way to turn this "feature" off?

Thanks.

/ Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity#onContentChanged` is not for 'updating' the data for the activity. It is called when the content view of the activity changes, i.e., when `Activity#setContentView` is called. The `ListActivity` will reinitialize it's content view when it receives `onContentChanged`.

The answer is, you're doing it wrong, don't use `onContentChanged` the way you are using it. That is why you are seeing this unexpected behavior. Use another method to update the `ListView`, most probably by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from your `Adapter`.